# Short Time Series Granularity of Timestamps

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, arima, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have to make a prediction on a time series whereby there are 10 years of data. My first option is to predict the values aggregated to the annual level using SARIMAX (excluding the seasonality component, but want to include some exogenous variables that are likely to explain the variations in Y). However that would lead to only 10 data points which might lead to overfitting and inaccurate predictions.

My second option is to predict the values at its original level (monthly). Then I would need to include the seasonal components of SARIMAX, but I'm not sure if that would make the overfitting issue better or worse. Also, I ideally want to get the predictions at an annual level.

I have looked at simpler models like random walk or exponential smoothing, but using the domain knowledge, I think the inclusion of the exogenous variables are very important to the prediction accuracy hence I prefer to use a model that can include these.

Comment: I understand the exogeneous variables are yearly?  One way could be to simply repeat those yearly values 12 times, and use as a predictor that way ... but look through [tag:unevenly-spaced-time-series]

Comment: There are some yearly and some monthly exogenous variables, but I think the problem I'm having right now is whether its suitable to fit ARIMA onto a time series with only 10 points (if I aggregate the monthly data to that level), since I heard elsewhere that it may end up overfitting, thanks :)

Comment: I doubt that arima on a series of length 10 makes much sense, but it will also depend on context --- how much noise is there in your series? If you can tell us some context, what does your series represent, etc  the probability of getting an answer from some of the time-series experts here could increase!